# directX 11 scale texture2D

Tags: c++, directx, gpu, directx-11

I would like to scale a texture I created from AcquireNextFrame.
Here is my code :

```
if (gRealTexture == nullptr) {
        D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC description;
        texture2D->GetDesc(&description);
        description.BindFlags = 0;
        description.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ | D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
        description.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
        description.MiscFlags = 0;
        hr = gDevice->CreateTexture2D(&description, NULL, &gRealTexture);
        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            if (gRealTexture) {
                gRealTexture->Release();
                gRealTexture = nullptr;
            }
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    gImmediateContext->CopyResource(gRealTexture, texture2D);
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mapped;
    hr = gImmediateContext->Map(gRealTexture, 0, D3D11_MAP_READ_WRITE, 0, &mapped);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        gRealTexture->Release();
        gRealTexture = NULL;
        return NULL;
    }
    unsigned char *source = static_cast<unsigned char *>(mapped.pData); //Here I get the pixel buffer data
```

Problem is that it is in Full HD Resolution (1920x1080). I would like to decrease the resolution (1280x720 for example) because I need to send `source` over network. And I don't really need a Full HD image.

Is it possible to do it with DirectX easily before I get the pixel buffer ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a smaller resolution texture, render the `texture2d` to the smaller texture using a fullscreen quad (but shrinking to the new size).  Make sure bilinear filtering is on.

Then copy and map the smaller texture. CopyResource needs the same dimensions.

Some resources:

[DX11 Helper Library](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK)
[Render To Texture](http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut22.html)

[DX11 Post Processing blur](http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut36.html)

The blur setup is the same as what I'm talking about, only instead of using a blur shader you use a simple texture shader.

Comment: Please can you show me some code ? I just need to create a new texture then I copy the previous in this one ? Using CopyResource?

Comment: I created a second texture and I put this description : But the copy map is failing :
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC description;
   texture2D->GetDesc(&description);
   description.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
   description.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
   description.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
   description.MiscFlags = 0;
   description.Width = 1280;
   description.Height = 720;
   hr = gDevice->CreateTexture2D(&description, NULL, &gScaledTexture);

Comment: I'm assuming you can render to the smaller texture, you're just having problems mapping it?

Comment: How to render on the smaller texture ? It would be nice if I can have a sample code from mine.. Maybe with SpriteBatch? But how ?...

Comment: The DX11 Post Processing Blur is literally rendering a fullscreen texture to the another texture for the horizontal blur pass.  With full source code examples.  Instead of doing a blur, you want to render the fullscreen down to a smaller texture, which uses a standard texturing shader instead of blur.  This is very fast on the GPU.

Comment: So I have to create .hlsl shaders to do it ? Do you know SpriteBatch from DX11 Helper Library ? Someone told me that I can do it very easily with this

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Inc/SpriteBatch.h#L78